# How to add image to checkedtextview in android

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I can add an image to checkedtxt view with the following xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/fIconImg" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/fTitleTxt" android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/favoriteChkTxtVw"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

However when I do this, the checkboxes in each row of the listview it is in does not click.  When the row layout consists of only a checktextview then the checkboxes check no problem.

Does anyone know how I can have a checkedtxtview in my row with the ability to check and uncheck while also maintaining the image and text view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your checkbox image?

try taking the "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"" off the Checkedtextview, and have it only for the first view item.